# Visual Studio 2008: Code Cleanup is not selectable

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, resharper, code-cleanup

I am very new to Visual Studio but i would like to use it to reorder my methods in my files. I have installed ReSharper and setup the code cleanup to do only one thing (reorder the methods). Now my problem is that when i go to select code cleanup under the Resharper -> Tools -> Cleanup Code, i cannot select it. The cleanup code is greyed out. Is there something that i have to do to the file in order to be able to clean it up? i am just opening a c++ file from my computer and attempting to select cleanup code. I tried creating a project and putting the file in that but still no luck.

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper doesn't supports C++. More about supported stuff here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resharper or here: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/.
For C++ you may try Visual Assist X, but I didn't used it and don't know much about it.